# How to filter marketplace vehicles with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am doing `/vehicles?limit=300&filter=[{"field":"vehicle_id", "value":"106892", "operator": "EQUAL"}]` and then getting error  `(#100) For field 'vehicles': Param filter must be a valid WCA rule.`.

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{catelog_id}/vehicles?limit=300&filter=%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22vehicle_id%22%2C%20%22value%22%3A%22106892%22%2C%20%22operator%22%3A%20%22EQUAL%22%7D%5D&access_token=<access token sanitized>"

==== Parameters
- Query Parameters
  {
    "limit": "300",
    "filter": "[{\"field\":\"vehicle_id\", \"value\":\"106892\", \"operator\": \"EQUAL\"}]"
  }
- POST Parameters
  {}
==== Response
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "(#100) For field 'vehicles': Param filter must be a valid WCA rule.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "xxx"
    }
  }
```

Facebook Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/vehicles/. I cannot find any clear guide how this filter should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [filter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/products/) field should be a valid `JSON-encoded WCA rule expression representing the filter to be applied for the edge`. You could find reference for this definition [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/website-custom-audiences) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-set#) (`Filter Rules`, se also the `Example Filter Rules` section). In your example, should be something like:

```
/vehicles?filter={"vehicle_id":{"eq":"106892"}}
```

Comment: How do multi filter? with and